# Proportional Sorting in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with 125k records. Each day, I insert ~20 records and generate 1,000 notifications based on the top 1000 records in the table ordered by insert time. Once notifications are generated, they are marked and no longer considered for future notification delivery. This has worked fine for a long time, except that a large insert of 100k which was ordered in a weird manner causes some issues.

There are 4 types of records, 2 columns with two different values each determines which of these 4 types it is. Based on the file sorting, one of the types is in the first 80k records and dominates the daily notifications.

I am working to fix this by creating a trigger on insert that will reorder the table in a manner that there is more evenly dispersed notifications each day.

My question: Is there a built in SQL Sorting Function that can proportionally sort results based on data in a column?

i.e. Can I get an 80/20 split based on column A and underneath, get an 80/20 split based on column B so that if I have the below options, I get 640 Records of (1,1), 160 records of (1,2), 160 records of (2,1), and 40 records of (2,2) without doing a hard coded `select top X` statement, as there are times I won't have 640 (1,1) records, but I still want 1000 total notifications generated.

```
Column A    Column B
1           1
1           2
2           1
2           2
```

Comment: Tables don't have an "order". If you're counting on some accidental ordering within a table then you're making a grave mistake. If you want an order to your result set then you need to use the `ORDER BY` clause and specify what that order is.

Comment: I'd suggest building a dynamic statement with `top` and `union`. This way you'd always get your 1000 results.

Comment: Also, please include your table structures. What are the rules if one of the types is short rows? Do you grab them from a specific other type? What's the ordering of the types on which one should be used for replacement rows?

Comment: @TomH - An Identity int column is used for ordering for the notifications at this time. The data is inserted based on the ordering in the file. The problem is that one file was very large and ordered in such a way that (1,2) records were the first 80K rows in the file. This normally would not happen as we only add ~20 per day.

Comment: The problem isn't the file. The problem is that you tried to rely on an `IDENTITY` column to create ordering in a table. If you need the order to match some type of rules then you need to define those rules and enforce them. Relying on them being in a file in a certain way and being inserted in a certain way that causes the identity to act a certain way is not a good plan.

Comment: @TomH - I 100% agree. But unfortunately, this process was built 6 years ago, well before I took it over. It hadn't had an issue before because the volume was low enough that ordering of the file did not matter. Most days, we did not even hit the 1000 notification limit as there weren't enough new records to send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `ROW_NUMBER` to achieve what you want. You didn't provide table structures, so some of this is guesswork:

```
;WITH CTE_NumberedRows AS
(
    SELECT
        id,
        column_a,
        column_b,
        some_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column_a, column_b ORDER BY some_date) AS row_num
    FROM
        My_Table
)
SELECT TOP 1000
    id,
    column_a,
    column_b
FROM
    CTE_NumberedRows
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN column_a = 1 AND column_b = 1 AND row_num <= 640 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    CASE WHEN column_a = 1 AND column_b = 2 AND row_num <= 160 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    CASE WHEN column_a = 2 AND column_b = 1 AND row_num <= 160 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    CASE WHEN column_a = 2 AND column_b = 2 AND row_num <= 40  THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    some_date
```

Whether or not you need to order by the date in `ASC` or `DESC` order isn't clear (or if you're even ordering on a date.) Hopefully the general gist of how it can be done is enough though. You're prioritizing (via the `ORDER BY` and `CASE` statements) the first "x" rows from each type and then after that just by the date.

Comment: I was able to update with my Column Names and Table Name and this worked perfectly. Will probably update a little bit but this is great. Thank you